# Getting a error while installing the Microsoft web deploy 3.6 saying verify you have sufficient privileges to start the system services

Tags: iis-8, webdeploy

I have installed the .net framework on a new server and want to install the web deploy 3.6 but I am getting the error attached.
Using the below exe screenshot attached to install the program.[Error and Exe picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ppKa.png)
I have done all the server manager settings and checked the user and groups permission but no luck.

Comment: Are you logged into the server as an administrator to install it? Right-click the Web Deploy installer and select "Run as administrator" to start the installer with elevated privileges.

Comment: yes we login as administrator, our web management service when checked in services is disabled and that is why it is not allowing to install, any packages we need to install to enable the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following limitations may create issues when using the MSI instead of Web PI to install Web Deploy on servers:

1. The MSI will not install SQL Shared Management Objects (SMO), which is required for the SQL Server database deployments. This component may be installed using Web PI to enable SQL Server database deployments.
2. The MSI will not install the Web Management Service handler component if the Web Management Service is not installed. The handler component is necessary for non-administrator deployments. Windows component IIS, including Management Service, should be installed first to enable the handler component to install.
3. When Web Deploy is installed directly using the Web Deploy MSI, the Web Management Service will not be configured for non-administrator deployments, unless PowerShell v2 or later is installed.

To install Web Deploy from the .msi file:

1. Go to the [Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) download page.
2. On the Web Deploy download page, move to the Download Web Deploy section, and for the language you want, select x86 or x64.
3. Run the Web Deploy .msi, and move through the installer wizard, selecting the features that you want in the Custom Setup page.

[image: Web Deploy Custom Setup]

For more details, please refer to this article: [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy on IIS 8.0 or Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later)